# Android : Not able to stop the audio from the same button

Tags: android

I'm working on an app in which there is a grid layout with 8 buttons and each attached to a sound. Now I'm able to play the audio on the click of a button but when I press the same button again the audio doesn't stop.

All my buttons are attached to a common onClick method and the class file retrieves the id of the button and matches with the sound file present in the raw folder.

I'm using a flag for this but don't know where I'm going wrong.

My Code

```
    boolean play = true;
    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



    }

    public void buttonTapped(View view)
    {



        int id = view.getId();
        String ourID = "";



        ourID = view.getResources().getResourceEntryName(id);

        int resourceID = getResources().getIdentifier(ourID, "raw", "com.starprojects.gridlayoutdemo");
        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this,resourceID);


        if(play)
        {

            mediaPlayer.start();
            play = false;
        }
        else {


        //  mediaPlayer.stop();

           mediaPlayer.release();
            mediaPlayer = null;



         //   play = true;
        }

       // mediaPlayer = null;

        Log.i("button tapped",ourID);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

define mediaPlayer outsite of function, then do that

```
public void buttonTapped(View view) {
        int id = view.getId();
        String ourID = "";

        ourID = view.getResources().getResourceEntryName(id);

        int resourceID = getResources().getIdentifier(ourID, "raw", "com.starprojects.gridlayoutdemo");

        stopPlayer();
        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this,resourceID);
            if (mediaPlayer != null)
                mediaPlayer .start();
}


public void stopPlayer() {
            if (mediaPlayer != null) {
                mediaPlayer .stop();
                mediaPlayer .release();
            }
            mediaPlayer = null;
}
```

thats all :)

Answer (score 0):

This may or may not be related to your problem, but don't forget to call

```
mediaPlayer.release();
mediaPlayer = null;
```

when you are finished. If you do not, resources get built up and start affecting sound outside of the app. Keep in mind a new MediaPlayer is being allocated every time you press the button. I have done this in a previous app and the sound stopped working after a few minutes.

Let me know if this changes anything.

As a matter of fact, you can try making your MediaPlayer a member of the class (defined outside the function) since you only need one sound playing at once. If it isn't null or .isPlaying(), release it. Otherwise, create and play.

Comment: one solution is to get id of particular button inside oncreate method

Comment: yeah i want to use media player outside the method but it is getting view of the button which is assigned to resource ID and because of that I can't assign it outside.

Comment: @sunny Wait what? Can you explain that again

Comment: Define it outside the methods and set it inside the method with the RID?

Comment: I have defined mediaPlayer outside and inside the else block i'm using mediaPlayer.release() and play = true But it is not working